# The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1, ninject, httpmodule

I try to make custom error handling (http://perspectivespace.com/100497697) with error module(Application_Error), HttpModuleMagic.MVC3, Ninject.MVC3, EF 4.1. Unfortunately when I want to log the error into the database it gives this error message:
"The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed."

Could somebody help me, please?

```
public class ErrorHandlerHttpModule : IHttpModule
{
    private const string ErrorControllerRouteName = "Error";
    private IErrorRepository errorRepo;
    private IUserRepository userRepo;

  //  private IUserRepository UserRepository;

    public ErrorHandlerHttpModule(IErrorRepository er, IUserRepository ur)
    {
        errorRepo = er;
        userRepo = ur;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.Error += Application_Error;
    }

    private void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Get the last error.

        var exception = HttpContext.Current.Server.GetLastError();
    ...

    error.User = userRepo.GetUserByName(name);

    ...
```

In the NinjectWebCommon.cs:

```
    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Bind<IErrorRepository>().To<ErrorRepository>().InRequestScope();
        kernel.Bind<IUserRepository>().To<UserRepository>().InRequestScope();

        kernel.Bind<IDatabaseFactory>().To<DatabaseFactory>().InRequestScope();

        kernel.Bind<IDisposable>().To<Disposable>().InRequestScope();
        kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<ErrorHandlerHttpModule>();
    }
```

... and the UserRepository class:

```
public class UserRepository : RepositoryBase<User>, IUserRepository
{
    public UserRepository(IDatabaseFactory databaseFactory)
    : base(databaseFactory)
    {
    } 

    public User GetUserByName(string name)
    {
        User us = null;
        try
        {
            us = dataContext.Users.Where(u => u.UserName.Equals(name)).FirstOrDefault() as User;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        return us;
    }
}
```

The RepositoryBase:

```
public abstract class RepositoryBase<T> where T : class
{
    protected TestContext dataContext;
    private readonly IDbSet<T> dbset;
    protected RepositoryBase(IDatabaseFactory databaseFactory)
    {
        DatabaseFactory = databaseFactory;
        dbset = DataContext.Set<T>();
    }

    protected IDatabaseFactory DatabaseFactory
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    protected TestContext DataContext
    {
        get { return dataContext ?? (dataContext = DatabaseFactory.Get()); }
    }
    ...
```

and DatabaseFactory class:

```
public class DatabaseFactory : Disposable, IDatabaseFactory
{
    private TestContext dataContext;

    public TestContext Get()
    {
        return dataContext ?? (dataContext = new TestContext());
    }

    protected override void DisposeCore()
    {
        if (dataContext != null)
            dataContext.Dispose();
    }
}
```

This line dives the error:

```
dataContext.Users.Where(u => u.UserName.Equals(name)).FirstOrDefault() as User;
```

I try to follow this article:
http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2011/01/06/developing-web-apps-using-asp-net-mvc-3-razor-and-ef-code-first-part-1.aspx

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Better yet, where did you create an instance of the dataContext? And where did you close it?

Comment: Many, many thanks. I sweat with it some days.

Comment: Has this been resolved?  If so can you please post your code so that I can see what you did?  I have similar code and a similar error.  Thanks :)

Comment: As I remember it was caused by the wrong usage of Ninject.

Comment: That is about as helpful as you can get without being any help at all. There is a million different wrongful usage of Ninject. Care to elaborate?

Comment: OK. As I remember I've put this error.User = userRepo.GetUserByName(name); task into a service class: userService.AddError(error, name); I'm sorry but I really do not remember it. This is my first MVC3 app and it's full of problems. Good luck. And I emptied the DisposeCore method. I'll try to reproduce the problem. :)

Comment: I had to dispose the context and set it to null and set also the dbset to null in BaseRepository class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
protected override void DisposeCore()
{
   if (dataContext != null)
   {
      dataContext.Dispose();
      dataContext = null;
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The reason for this is that your LINQ query is deferred, in other words it is not run in your "UserRepository" but only in the calling code. So the DBContext has already been disposed of when it is executed. You can force it to execute immediately by changing

```
us = dataContext.Users.Where(u => u.UserName.Equals(name)).FirstOrDefault() as User
```

to

```
us = dataContext.Users.Where(u => u.UserName.Equals(name)).ToList().FirstOrDefault() as User
```